# django: Make better looking multiple select menus in admin as displayed in auth>user tables

Tags: django

I have a User model that has these two fields:

```
permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

I register the model in the admin.  When I view the user model that I made in the admin section I get a multiple select menu that looks like this.
[image]

I would much prefer the much better-looking menu like the one that is in the auth user model that comes built into Django admin (looks like this)
[image]

Any ideas on what I need to do to be able to access this sort of select menu?
Thanks for your help.
Django newb from PHP (finally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter_horizontal (or filter_vertical) field in your admin class.
For example:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    filter_horizontal = 'groups', 'permissions', 'any_other_m2m_field'
    ...
```

Also link to Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal